# How can I add a state to a control in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have my own TextBox2 class that derives from TextBox.  I want to add a state called TextBlock and I want the VisualStateManager to go to that state when the IsTextBlock property/dependency property is true.  When this is true, I want to change the style of the text box to be readonly and look just like a TextBlock but be able to select the text to be copyable.  Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "TextBlock", GroupName = "ControlType")]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "TextBox", GroupName = "ControlType")]
public class TextBox2 : TextBox
{
    public TextBox2()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof (TextBox2);
        Loaded += (s, e) => UpdateVisualState(false);
    }


    private bool isTextBlock;
    public bool IsTextBlock
    {
        get { return isTextBlock; }
        set
        {
            isTextBlock = value;
            UpdateVisualState(true);
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        UpdateVisualState(false);
    }


    internal void UpdateVisualState(bool useTransitions)
    {
        if (IsTextBlock)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "TextBlock" , useTransitions);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "TextBox" , useTransitions);
        }
    }
}
```

HTH